# Slicing using arrays/indices

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am trying to iteratively access an numpy array using indices and arrays.
The following example pretty much sums up my problem:

```
x = np.arange(12)
x.shape = (3,2,2)
nspace = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
for it in range(len(nspace)):
    x[:,nspace(it)] = np.array([1,1,1])
```

If things worked the way I am thinking, the code would print 4 separate arrays:

```
[0,4,8]
[1,5,9]
[2,6,10]
[3,7,11]
```

But I get an error. I understand the my indexing is wrong, but I cannot figure out how to get the result I want.

It is important that everything happens within a loop because I want to be able to change the dimensions of x.

EDIT0: I need a general solution that does require. me to write: space[0,0], space[0,1], etc.

EDIT1: I changed the print to an assignment operation because what actually need is to assign the result of a function that I call inside the loop.

EDIT2: I did not include the Traceback because I doubt it will be useful. Anyway, here it is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-600-50905b8b5c4d>", line 5, in <module>
    print(x[:,nspace(it)])

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: "But I get an error": it's always good to show the actual error in your question (including the full traceback). Here, it may look obvious, but otherwise, the error can be immensely useful.

Comment: It would be a lot of help if you post the stack trace for errors you encounter. I assume an IndexError exception was thrown, but that's just speculation without a stack trace

Comment: You're spending a lot of time adding EDITs and not reviewing the two working answers that already solved the problem before you posted them (which do not invalidate either approach)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `for` loop. Use `reshape` and `transpose`.

```
x.reshape(3, 4).T
```

Gives:

```
array([[ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 1,  5,  9],
       [ 2,  6, 10],
       [ 3,  7, 11]])
```

If you wanted to iterate the result:

```
for row in x.reshape(3, 4).T:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Three birds killed with a single shot ;)

Comment: @Bazingaa yeah and now I'm pondering your answer because I might be over-complicating?

Comment: Out of respect, I didn't dare to say a thing on your answer. But yes, it looked a bit too much condensed, though perfectly fine :)

Comment: @Bazingaa I'm not so concerned about chaining the operations - this is array programming after all :) But have I got an unnecessary step? I think the `ravel()` is necessary but part of me thinks there's a shorter route.

Comment: `x.reshape(3, 4).T` works too. ravel isn't necessary in this case

Comment: @Bazingaa duh (me) ofc it does. The reshape was the one thing I wasn't thinking about properly. Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is that I need to assign the output of a function to the array in each iteration of the loop, so this. wouldn't work.  I changed my example accordingly.

Comment: @FranciscoAndrés So iterate through the new array that has been created

Answer (score 0):

You get the error, because you should have square brackets for element access on the last line.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(12)
x.shape = (3,2,2)
nspace = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
for it in range(len(nspace)):
    print(x[:,nspace[it]])
```

EDIT:

And one possible solution to get your expected result:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(12)
x.shape = (3,2,2)
nspace = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])

y = x.flatten()

for i in range(x.size//x.shape[0]):
    print y[i::4]
```

Comment: ... did you run this?

Comment: Yeah. I know that it gives a bad result, I only wanted to point out the cause of error in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the first and the second index and use `[]` brackets instead of `()` to access the array elements.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(12)
x.shape = (3,2,2)

for it in range(len(nspace)):
    print(x[:,nspace[it][0], nspace[it][1]])
```

---

**Output**

```
[0 4 8]
[1 5 9]
[ 2  6 10]
[ 3  7 11]
```

You can also use `reshape` directly as

```
x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,2,2)
```